# Does restoring dd image override whole disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a PC running ubuntu 12 (dedicated) that I have created a dd image from, and another laptop with ubuntu as dual-boot with windows 7.
What I have done is I have taken that image from the PC, and tried to clone it to the laptop driver on ubuntu, but later after restarting the computer, the hardisk doesn't boot anything any longer.

I have tried using a HDD case to use the hard disk as an external HDD in a PC, the disk utility shows the HDD volume as unknown, and the partition type as Linux(0x83).
Did I just erase my whole data? and what can I do from this point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What command did you use ?

When you did it like (example here) :

dd if=/dev/sdb(external harddisk) of=/dev/sda(notebook)

Then you have overriden your notebook.

When /boot partition is located e.g. in sda3 and you have not-of-use-files in sda4 (sda1 and sda2 are swap) - then you could make

dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda4

But you have probably to edit the boot-files in sda3 for to fix them to sdb written in sda4.

Now anything is overriden - and then only testdisk can help to restore the files,
who have been there before dd. - but his works only with journaling filesystems.

Testdisk or photorec take very long time for to recover - you can do that overnight.

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/420
http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Rescuing-Lost-Files-with-TestDisk-and-PhotoRec